# Un-assign MenuCommandKey

Tags: customization, stylesheet, assignment

In my StyleSheet, I would like to assign to the environment `Subchapter` the Key Alt+2 (via `MenuCommandKey`. However, this is precisely already assigned to `Subtitle`. Can I therefore first remove that default assignment and put it on `Subchapter` instead?

Comment: Just add and remove in the stylesheet as appropriate. However, if you create a Chapter cell, and then hit Tab, it will turn into a Subchapter cell. Maybe that's sufficient for you?

Comment: To add onto what @CarlWoll said, you can assign `MenuCommandKey->None` to turn it off and `MenuCommandKey->2` for the other one you want to map it onto. Sometimes you need to do that when inheritance gets in the way.